# My code isn't recognizing a condition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this following problem (Udacity's Intro to Javascript):

> Directions:
>   Write a loop that prints out the following song. Starting at 99, and ending at 1 bottle.
>
> Example:
>
> 99 bottles of juice on the wall! 99 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 98 bottles of juice on the wall!
>
> 98 bottles of juice on the wall! 98 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it 
>   around... 97 bottles of juice on the wall!
>
> ...
>
> 2 bottles of juice on the wall! 2 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 1 bottle of juice on the wall!
>
> 1 bottle of juice on the wall! 1 bottle of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 0 bottle**s** of juice on the wall!

and my code doesn't appropriately output the last line (it doesn't include "s" after "bottle"):

My code looks like this:

```
 var num = 99;

 while (num >= 1) {

 num == 1 ? ((plural = "") && (nextPlural = "s")) :
 num == 2 ? ((plural = "s") && (nextPlural = "")) :
 ((plural = "s") && (nextPlural = "s"));

 console.log (num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice on the wall! " + num + "bottle" + plural + " of juice! " + "Take one down, pass it around... " + (num - 1) + " bottle" + nextPlural + " of juice on the wall!");
 num = num - 1
 }
```

why is this code ignoring my condition for "num == 2?" at the last line of output?

FYI, I was able to solve this using the following code, but it didn't look clean so I wanted to optimize this:

```
var num = 99;
var plural = "s";
var nextNum = num - 1;
var nextPlural = "s";

while (num >= 1) {
if (num > 1 && nextNum > 1){
plural = "s";
nextPlural = "s";
}
else if (num > 1 && nextNum == 1){
plural = "s";
nextPlural = "";
}
else if (num == 1 && nextNum <= 1){
    plural = "";
    nextPlural = "s";
}
console.log(num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottle"+ plural + " of juice! " +
"Take one down, pass it around... " + nextNum + " bottle" + nextPlural + " of juice on the wall!");
num = num - 1;
nextNum = num - 1;
}
```

Comment: No *screenshot of the exercise*. Copy and paste the text. Consider people reading this site on a mobile device, or people behind corporate proxies that don't allow images. Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem. The same goes for the image of console.log - it's text that can be copied and pasted into your post here.

Comment: My apologies. I thought having screenshots would make this look more organized and easier to read. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why did you decide to use a ternary operator to do the conditionals? Why did you not just use if statements. Using ternaries like this make it harder to see what's happening

Comment: francium// I actually solved this using a different method but it looked too complicated.. So I tried to extend my ability and try to simplify the code. Is this a bad method? (I will update this with my original code)

Comment: @81ackCat yes. Horrible. You've shot yourself in the foot here :P and made it more complicated. Ternary operators should be used in cases such as `x = condition ? a : b`. This is to avoid using an if statement when you're just going to assign a value based on a condition.

Comment: @francium Thank you for your input! As a beginner, I wasn't too sure what  the "best practice" in terms of how the code should look. Is it safer to think if the code is longer, it is better?

Comment: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler." Don't sacrifice readability in order to show how clever you are. You'll learn from experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the question, if I understand it right, is why the last line for the first code sample outputs "0 bottle" instead of "0 bottles".

So let's translate **what you attempted to achieve** with your code into English and figure out what the interpreter does:

1. Set `num` to 99.
2. While `num` greater or equal to 1, do the following:

   2.1 If `num` equals 1, set `plural` to `""` and `nextPlural` to `"s"`.

   2.2 Else if `num` equals 2, set `plural` to `"s"` and `nextPlural` to `""`.

   2.3 Else set both `plural` and `nextPlural` to `"s"`.
3. The console output is trivial, so I won't mention it here.
4. Set `num` equal to `num-1`.

You might notice that substituting the ternary operator with an `if` statement yields the correct result:

```js
var num = 1;
var plural = '';
var nextPlural = '';

while (num >= 1) {

if(num==1) { plural = ''; nextPlural='s'; }

/*num == 1 ? ((plural = "") && (nextPlural = "s")) : (num == 2 ? ((plural = "s") && (nextPlural = "")) : ((plural = "s") && (nextPlural = "s")));*/

console.log (num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice! " + "Take one down, pass it around... " + (num - 1) + " bottle" + nextPlural + " of juice on the wall!");
num = num - 1

}
```

What does that mean? That there is a syntax error with your use of the ternary operator. What could it possibly be? Let's declare a new variable and try setting and outputting it along with the others.

```js
var num = 1;
var plural = '';
var nextPlural = '';
var test = '';

while (num >= 1) {

//if(num==1) { plural = ''; nextPlural='s'; }

num == 1 ? ((plural = "") && (nextPlural = "s") && (test = "test")) : (num == 2 ? ((plural = "s") && (nextPlural = "")) : ((plural = "s") && (nextPlural = "s")));

console.log (num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice! " + "Take one down, pass it around... " + (num - 1) + " bottle" + nextPlural + " of juice on the wall!");
console.log(test);
num = num - 1

}
```

You will notice that `test` remains equal to an empty string, just like `nextPlural`. That's because [using `&&` is not the correct way of instantiating variables inside ternary constructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), so this code will work as intended:

```js
var num = 99;
var plural = '';
var nextPlural = '';

while (num >= 1) {

//if(num==1) { plural = ''; nextPlural='s'; }

num == 1 ? (plural = "", nextPlural = "s") : (num == 2 ? (plural = "s", nextPlural = "") : (plural = "s", nextPlural = "s"));

console.log (num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottle" + plural + " of juice! " + "Take one down, pass it around... " + (num - 1) + " bottle" + nextPlural + " of juice on the wall!");
--num;

}
```

If you are interested, this is how I would probably program the solution:

```js
for(var i=99, w=' on the wall!'; i>0; i--) {
 console.log(returnEmpties(i)+w+' '+returnEmpties(i)+'! Take one down, pass it around... '+returnEmpties(i-1)+w);
}

function returnEmpties(n) { return n+' bottle'+(n==1?'':'s')+' of juice'; }
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help!! I guess I was extending too much -- I haven't learned how to use comma yet. Thank you!!

Comment: @81ackCat, I have added my own solution to the problem to my post should you be interested. The comma is just a punctuation mark that's used to separate instructions inside ternary operator blocks, much like the semicolon is used otherwise. `&&` is a logical operator used for comparison. Think of it as a function that returns a result (`a && b` is similar to `logicalAnd(a, b)`: it's 1 statement, not 2).

Comment: @81ackCat, if you are interested in how `&&` is evaluated with the assignment operator (`=`), [it's actually a very simple test](https://jsfiddle.net/4zwaeuvg/). I've done it because my initial explanation ("`&&` is wrong, use `,`") is actually pretty bad at showing what was happening in your code. In simple terms, the statement `var string=""` equates to `false`, and if one of the 2 statements united by a `&&` returns `false`, then both statements are reverted (neither one gets executed). Let me know if this makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator stuff is just a big mess, I've tried to figure it out, but it's really worth trying to fix since it's just not a good idea to use ternary operators like that. You've nested a ternary inside another ternary and basically have an `if, else if, else` condensed into 3 lines.

You can avoid doing extra logic and realize that you need only add an 's' when the number is not 1.

By extracting this logic into a function that returns the string `'s'` or the empty string `''`, you can simply plug this function into your loop and provide it with `n` and `n-1`.

```
function plural(n) {
  return n == 1 ? '' : 's';  // note this is the appropriate usage of a ternary operator
}
```

You can then simply your loop to just

```
while (num >= 1) {
  console.log('...');  // left as an exercise for you to fill in the required function call and string concatenations.
  num--;  // same thing as num = num - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I wish I can select more than one answers as solutions, but the site won't let me... I really appreciate it!